# Allow user to type in multi values instead of selecting

Tags: sql, reporting-services

In SSRS 2008R2, how it is possible to allow a user type in multi values instead of selecting?

The report must have multiple filters and all are optional where user can select one or any parameter to filter. Transaction # and category code are parameters where its required allowing the user type in values or select.

Parameters are as below
from date: 
To Date:
Transaction #:
Category code:

Using a multi value parameter where available values are based on a query is not a solution as the result will have a very long list and user wont be able to type in. thus we need the user to type the values to be filtered on.

transaction# is an integer and user may enter one or many or just keep it blank to get the result based on other used filters.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work with an embedded query:

First set up your parameter with data type Text and to Allow multiple values.

[image: parameter setup]

Since the parameter needs to be optional, set a default value (such as All) and update the WHERE clause in your query to get results based on this parameter:

```
...
WHERE ('All' IN (@Customer) OR CustomerNumber IN (@Customer))
...
```

Now when you run the report you can highlight the default value in the dropdown:

[image: highlight All in the dropdown and start typing]

and start typing in the values to search on (using Enter between each item):

[image: example of typed in values]

Comment: How would you show the customer account #s in the report body?

Comment: @BuddingProgrammer If you mean displaying the account numbers entered in the parameter, you could use an expression like `Join(Parameters!Customer.Value, "|")` in a textbox in the report body

Answer (score -1):

the only solution integrated into SSRS i found so far is to sue single valued text parameters to be parsed by the underlying database.

multi-valued parameters are replaced by single valued parameters, your users can fill them as they please, you have to split/validate these input values in the report code or at the sql layer.
this is very quick to implement and integrated into SSRS but has some (imho) huge drawback: input validation and error handling.

if an external solution is an option you can go with an asp.net report viewer.
leveraging on web scripting, ajax and so on the input interface can be very user friendly while keeping SSRS as a backend to do the heavy work.

Comment: when setting the parameter as multi value, we are not able to type in anything!!! what is missing here?

Comment: please see my edit. you have to use single valued parameters for each and every parameter whichever the datatype. cumbersome, clumsy to handle and requires input sanitizing and validation but do not requires external tools.